# How to generate <%= csrf_meta_tags %> in public/index.html file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, devise, csrf-protection

I use Backbone on frontend, and Ruby on Rails on backend. I have devise gem, for my authentication. A couple of days before, frontend team, finished their part of work, and now I need to bind this all together. So I try to send data with json trough backbone (standard way) with request `Started POST "/users/sign_in.json"`, and I get an error `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 180ms` even if I put `protect_from_forgery except: :create` in my custom sessions controller. Like this:

```
class UserSessions::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    protect_from_forgery except: :create
    ......
end
```

How to omit this, or where i must generate my `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` so I can use this approach which I found on web:

```
App.csrfToken = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content');

Backbone.sync = (function(original) {
  return function(method, model, options) {
    options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', App.csrfToken);
    };
    original(method, model, options);
  };
})(Backbone.sync);
```

I can't move this back to standard rails assets pipeline, because the frontend was written separately from my backend, which is depended on require.js.

Comment: You need to render the tags somewhere on the front-end, using csrf_meta_tags.  Somewhere where you can get at them with Javascript.

Comment: the questions is `how to do this` I can't user .erb extensions in my public folder. If I do that, than my rails/views are loading ((

Comment: Okay, try adding this to your sessions controller just to turn off CSRF checking altogether:   skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the csrf_meta_tags into a partial, then make an ajax request from public/index to a method that returns that partial.

Comment: this might be a solution

Comment: Yes you where right, I add `window.onload = function (){$.post('csrf/generate_csrf_meta_tags', null, null, "script");}` to the bottom of my index.html. generate_csrf_meta_tags renders js.erb file from which I render html.haml file in which a have this meta_tags generated )))